# Set css variable equal to class property

Tags: css

**Set css variable equal to class property**

I want to set a css variable equal to the height of one of my divs.

I tried

```
:root{
    --height-of-div: .div1.height;
}

.div2{
    height: calc(--height-of-div/2);
}
```

But it is not working.  Please help.

Comment: It can't be done

Comment: this is not valid css syntax, it does not have variables

Comment: this is not possible without javascript

Comment: i assume you want to add logic directly to your css file, well, as stated above by others, you cannot do it with css. You should look at SCSS for what you are looking for

Comment: How would I do it in SCSS

Comment: give the static height to your variable and pass it thorough var(--<name>)

Comment: I use a dynamic height for my .div1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible using CSS alone. You could use jQuery, something like this:

```
function SetDivHeight() {
         $("#div2").css({'height':($("#div1").height())});
 }
```